# For loop ignoring isKindOfClass for uibuttons in scrollview

Tags: ios, for-loop, tags

I have code that creates, adds and tags unbuttons in a uiview which is itself in a uiscrollview. At a certain point I try to change (background color and image) some of the unbuttons with certain tags . The problem is if I choose the first button with tag 0 the for loop bombs out for the image change because either uiscrollview or the uiview do not have that method available. But I am trying to only target the unbuttons within the view (all synched up). If I pick any other buttons it works as expected. I could offset the tag from 0 to one instead but I want to know why my for loop does not work.

```
for (int i=0; i<[devicesArray count]; i++) {
    NSLog(@"red %i", i);

    for (UIView *subview in [uiv_ButtonsView subviews]) {
        if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
            int number = [[devicesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
            subview.alpha=1.0;
            [[subview viewWithTag:number] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            UIButton *btttn = (UIButton *)[subview viewWithTag:number];
            [btttn setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks - this is now working code:

```
for (int i=0; i<[devicesArray count]; i++) {
    int number = [[devicesArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
    [[uiv_Quilt viewWithTag:number] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [[uiv_Quilt viewWithTag:number] setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (UIView *subview in [uiv_ButtonsView subviews]) {
```

`subView` is a subview of uiv_ButtonsView

```
if([subview isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
```

`subView` is a `UIButton`

```
[[subview viewWithTag:number] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```

Hmmm. Now you're getting a subview *of* the UIButton, with tag 0 - this is the default tag for all views. You're in the private view hierarchy of the UIButton here, we've no idea what this is.

```
UIButton *btttn = (UIButton *)[subview viewWithTag:number];
```

Same again - you've told the compiler that you are getting a button back from this call, but you won't be. `subView` is already a button, buttons don't have other buttons as subviews.

```
[btttn setBackgroundImage:nil forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

So this line of code won't work.

I don't see why you either do all your operations on `subView`, or use `[uiv_ButtonsView viewWithTag:xx]` to get your button. In the latter case, you will need to start your tags at 1, since all views have a default tag of 0.

Comment: This clear walkthrough of the code - which I should have done for myself - helped me. My new code is posted above. Thanks to Rob Ryan for also sending me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

The `[subview viewWithTag:number]` doesn't make sense to me (your button, subview, presumably doesn't have further subviews). And the iteration through your devicesArray with a nested iteration through the uiv_ButtonsView doesn't makes sense either. If you're using tags, you shouldn't need to iterate through your uiv_ButtonsView's subviews, but rather you could have used `[uiv_ButtonsView viewWithTag:number]`.